# Table cell resizing past max-width

Tags: html, css, html-table, internet-explorer-8

I have a table that will display the name of camera and its model. The problem is when a name/model string is too long the cell gets resized and therefore makes the table body out of sync with the head.

```
<td>
    <div class="camera_details">
        <div class="camera_models">XXXCAMERAMODELXXX</div>
        <div class="camera_name">XXXCAMERANAMEXXX</div>
    </div>
</td>
```

This has CSS like so:

```
td{
    max-width: 144px;
}
.camera_details {
    max-width: 144px;
}
.camera_models {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.camera_name {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

The problem only exists on IE8 where the div get restricted due to max-width but the td element doesn't which still causes misalignment in the table.

Is the a way I can force the td to be a certain width regardless of the width of the children divs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define **table-layout:fixed;** in your `table`. Write like this:

```
table{
 table-layout:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could apply the following styles to your `div`'s:

```
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
```

You will also need to specify a `width`.